# Xamarin.iOS does not support running or debugging the previous version of your project

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2022

I've been trying to fix this issue for 3 hours and nothing. My entire google search looks purple and there is no solution. This error just keep popping up no matter what I do.

Tried adding a new iOS project.
Tried creating a completely new project. Same issue.

I've got an iPad plugged in externally with a USB type C cable to my laptop and I have set up all the developer requirements from apple to be able to access my device via visual studio.

Updated the iPad to the latest iOS version `16.1.1` installed iTunes from the Microsoft store and I can see my device as an optional device to deploy my app too.

Windows 10
Visual Studio 2022

I've got a mac mini to test using Simulator but I want to test this on a real device not a Simulator. Works fine on Simulators but not on real device while plugged into Windows.

There is no more information I can provide with the error because I myself do no get more to work with either.

Many Thanks in Advance

[image]

Image of the `.iOS/bin/iPhone/Debug`. There are also country-specific directories above the files.
[image]

Comment: have you tried rebuilding your solution?

Comment: Yes I have. I've cleaned it rebuilt it about 10 times. There is no difference. I do not have a clue on what is going on.

Comment: Have you tried running directly from the Mac?  Also, the fallback VS solution of "delete everything in bin/obj"

Comment: I have not tried running the app directly on real device from mac no. I have manually deleted bin/obj folders (forgot to add it to the post). I currently cannot test the mac as I'm no longer in the office and I do not own a mac at home. I doubt that would change anything at all. I need to be able to test both Android and iOS on windows.

Comment: After deleting ALL `bin` folders in your solution, most importantly **the one inside `YourProject.iOS` subfolder,** then build solution, does `YourProject.iOS/bin/iPhone/Debug` folder get created, and contain the files needed to run a debug version of the app? IIRC, for debug, that will be an `.exe` file, plus some `.dll`s. **If not, then Rebuild Solution is not building the iOS version**.

Comment: You connected the device to Windows and used Hot Restart to test it, right? I need to confirm with you, you said: "Tried adding a new iOS project." Is your project Xamarin.iOS or Xamarin.Forms? Because currently Hot Restart Only iOS apps built with Xamarin.Forms and iOS devices are supported.

Comment: @DongzhiWang-MSFT this is `Xamarin.Forms` as the tag suggests.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Yes, I have done this and cleaned my solution and rebuilt it and yes it creates the folder as you say. It also contains all the files you've mentioned. I'm extremely confused as even a brand-new project doesn't want to run either I get the same problem.

Comment: I have finally fixed this issue, I do not know how but I just kept deleting bin/obj folders from all the projects and cleaning and rebuilding the solution and it actually deployed onto the external device...

Answer (score 0):

I know OP has been able to solve this question himself, but I ended up with pretty much the same scenario and his fix "keep deleting bin/obj folder until it starts to work" didn't work for me.

So maybe someone will encounter this sometime in the future and these are the steps that finally fixed it for me. I have made them all at once, so I don't know which are actually meaningfull for this particular problem and I am not willing to jeopardize my current working environment to find out :D

1. I run "dotnet workload install ios". Still didn't work, but it may be important. Previously I installed iOS workload via Visual Studio installer.
2. Removed "Apple developer account" and added it once again.
3. In Apple account's "Company Details" I created a new "iOS Development certificate".
4. In "iOS Settings" I unchecked "Remote Simulator to Windows" (I don't even have Visual Studio connected to Xcode so this should have literally zero effect, but I just describing what I did in my desperation :D)
5. And in "Android Settings" I unchecked "Preserve application cache on device between deploys". My project is being built for Android, but I would expect that this option would not affect iOS deployment in any way. Similar to the previous point, I don't know if this actually made any difference.

After that, it magically started to work.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, this error message in VS just indicates that there is a new XCode update that has to be installed on the Mac.

1. Open App Store on the connected Mac
2. Go to "Updates"
3. Install

It is still a good idea to:

- clean up all bins/obj folders,
- clean solution,
- delete .vs file
- restart both machines
- do a rebuild.